# How to call a handler?

Tags: c++, boost, asio

I don't understand how I could return handle in case the `io_context` was stopped. Minimum example:

```
void my_class::async_get_one_scan(
    std::function<void(const boost::system::error_code& ec, 
                       std::shared_ptr<my_chunked_packet>)> handler)
{
    asio::spawn(strand_, [this, handler] (asio::yield_context yield)
    {
        const auto work = boost::asio::make_work_guard(io_service_);
        my_chunk_buffer chunks;

        while (!chunks.full()) {
            std::array<uint8_t, 1000> datagram;
            boost::system::error_code ec;
            auto size = socket_.async_receive(asio::buffer(datagram), yield[ec]);

            if (!ec)
                process_datagram(datagram, size, chunks);
            else {
                handler(ec, nullptr);
                return;
            }
        }

        io_service_.post(std::bind(handler, boost::system::error_code, chunks.packet()));
    });
}
```

Debug asio output:

```
@asio|1532525798.533266|6*7|strand@01198ff0.dispatch
@asio|1532525798.533266|>7|
@asio|1532525798.533266|>0|
@asio|1532525798.533266|0*8|socket@008e345c.async_receive
@asio|1532525798.533266|<7|
@asio|1532525798.533266|<6|
@asio|1532525799.550640|0|socket@008e34ac.close
@asio|1532525799.550640|0|socket@008e345c.close
@asio|1532525799.551616|~8|
```

So the last `async_receive() #8` is created, after `|<6|` `io_context.stop()` is called  and then I have no idea how to get the `error_code` from `yield_context` to call the handler.

question#2 is it even a correct way of async reading of chunks of data to collect the whole packet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, `io_context::stop` prevents the event loop from executing other handlers. So there's no way to get the exit code into the handler, because it doesn't get invoked.

You probably want to have a "soft-stop" function instead, where you stop admitting new async tasks to the io_context and optionally cancel any pending operations.

If pending operations could take too long, you will want to add a deadline timer that forces the cancellation at some threshold time interval.

The usual way to make the `run` loop exit is by releasing a `work` object. See https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context__work.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm basically implementing a test. For this purpose, I do `io_context.run_for()` and then I want to see that handler was called with `connection_aborted`. That's it. And what do you think about question#2?

Comment: The `aborted` case can be triggered by canceling the particular service object (so like a timer or socket)